# Problem with merging .csv files from folder

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to combine multiple .csv files from a folder on my computer. All of these .csv files have the same columns. Before running the code, I already set my working directory in RStudio to the location of my folder.

```
folder <- "FBI_2012"
filenames <- list.files(folder)

all_files <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv))
```

Every time I run the code I encounter this error message:
"Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection"

Comment: are you using RStudio to run your code?

Comment: Yes I'm using RStudio.

Comment: Make sure you are in the directory that contains ```FBI_2012``` and that you have set that as your working directory. You can do that on the ```Files``` tab using the ```More``` submenu and selecting ```Set as Working Directory```. Or you can set the path explicitly in your code for  ```folder <- "FBI_2012"```

Comment: To make sure that your path is correct irrespective of what your working directory is always use `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`. Do `filenames <- list.files(folder, full.names = TRUE)` check `filenames` to see if they have the correct path and then use `lapply` with `read.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the name of the folder to your file. If the column names in all the files are the same, this should work:

```
folder <- "FBI_2012"
filenames <- list.files(folder)

all_files <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(paste0(folder, '/', filenames), read.csv))
```

If you're already in the folder `"FBI_2012"`, then the `list.files` function won't find anything. If that's the case, you should use

```
# Get files in current working directory
filenames <- list.files(getwd())

all_files <- Reduce(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv))
```

instead.